Incredibly I seem to have got a bit stronger (doing my angle push ups) in only about 3 weeks - can this be right?
My general fitness is ok but I've never made an effort towards strength.  Hence, it is utterly impossible for me to do even one push up.  (I am 50s, 6', a bit overweight.)
I like the idea of just using body weight exercises and someone explained the obvious idea that if you hopelessly can't do a push up, you can do them on an angle - so, on some stairs say (or even a wall I guess).
I carefully worked out the exact step / foot position where I could just barely do about 6 or 7 such angle push ups, until failure.
FTR reading up as best I could I:

I read somewhere that count to three seconds up, hold for one seconds, count to three seconds down is an OK approach for each push up

I did sets of about 7, sometimes 8 if I could, to failure

I did three sets (often couldn't finish the last)

I'd wait roughly 2 mins between sets (longer sometimes when feeling slack)

I did this on alternate days

I think my form is pretty good as I'm the disciplined type

I eat a very clean diet, plenty of protein, good sleep etc and just for the hell of it I'd usually eat a bit of protein after my modest "workout" (I guess my "workout" would make everyone on here laugh!)


Amazingly I only started doing this ... well I have only done it ~12 times (ie about 30 days w/ rest days)
Incredibly, starting say a week ago when I rolled up to the staircase and got in position, I found it really easy - wtf?  I assumed, oh, I have my feet in the wrong place / hands on the wrong step, it seems to easy - but no! I hit all the marks!
Indeed, incredibly I can now pretty much do the next harder angle "!!!!" - which was utterly impossible for me (I'd just flop down) a whole 3-4 weeks ago.
My question experts.. can this possibly be true?
I seem to have gained a little bit, indeed in a way for me a LOT, of strength - from merely a couple weeks of this ???
What do you say?

Excellent - carry on progressing!

as others already said: congrats on your newbie gains / progressive overload success!

First, congrats on finding a program that you seem to enjoy sticking to!  That's the first step and usually the hardest.
As far as strength progression goes, the answer is yes. The body will adapt pretty quickly to new stimuli. In this case, you're challenging your muscles. This gave a signal that the muscles need to get stronger. You ate to fuel the adaptation. So your body adapted to accommodate this new environment. Additionally, you developed a new skill to be better at doing push-ups.
The effect is often referred to as "progressively overload". Which basically means you challenge yourself just a little bit so that the body adapts to the new stimulus.  The effect is of course greater in younger people, but it's been observed in people older than 70 years old.
So in your case, all you have to do is attempt your push-ups at a slightly harder difficulty. You can lower the angle, increase the number of sets, slow down each rep, etc.

wow just wow - GUSH

@Fattie Other than implied in this answer, most strength gains in the first few weeks do not have anything to do with structural developments but are almost exclusively due to neuromuscular adaptations, ie. your body learned the movement and how and when to activate more muscle fibres so that the movement is more efficient. Basically, your motor cortex told your muscles to move often enough and with enough verve so that the neural pathways work better plus your muscles and individual fibres learnt to better coordinate.

@PhilipKlöcking that is amazing.  Surely, you should paste that in as an answer as it would be so valuable to googlers over the decades?  I had heard that general concept, but never seen it explained as well

it occurs to me immediately that, then, doing radically varied grips, positions, etc, would far more lead to the process described

Fair warning that "newbie gains" are a thing, and progress will likely plateau, even with variation. :-D Just so that you can temper your enthusiasm a little bit with reasonable expectations.

@SeanDuggan - for sure!

Other than implied in DeeV's answer, most strength gains in the first few weeks do not have anything to do with structural developments but are almost exclusively due to neuromuscular adaptations. This means that your body learned the movement and how and when to activate more and "(only) the right" muscle fibres so that the movement is more efficient.
Basically, your motor cortex told your muscles to move often enough and with enough verve so that the neural pathways work better (in a sense, that is a form of hypertrophy but its not muscular!) plus your muscles and individual fibres learnt to better coordinate.
Those gains are called "beginner's gains" for a reason: They are pretty significant and fast compared to what's coming later.
Generally, you should alter low rep, max strength sets and higher rep, lower weight sets (up to 30 reps per set) in, for example, 3 week periods - of course with progressive overload near failure per set (up to 3 reps in reserve). That way, both your muscular structures and their metabolism as well as your neural system experience "new" input on a regular basis. According to the latest research, this is the way to gain strength and muscle mass.
Your gains will be more slowly eventually, though. So when you change the set patterns every 3 or 4 weeks, maybe assess your 1 rep max only then.
As of body weight exercise, as soon as you feel you could easily do 30 reps per set, you need to add weight. And, as said, it may well be worth the try to add weight for some time, even if you can only do 3-8 reps per set with that. That way, the speed of the structural adaptations of your tendons will be more in line with that of your muscles. Tendinopathy and ruptures are a well-known risk for enthusiastic beginners with high workload per week. That is because max strength training is much better a stimulus for tendons than high rep training and many beginners (after a few weeks/months) end up with crazy rep numbers of bodyweight exercises exactly due to the fast progress and the rush coming with it. The tendons don't become stronger much with this kind of stimulus and have to deal with much higher demands - leading to injury.

Awesome. Since you sadly can't tick more than one answer, I split the tick/bounty between the two incredible answers here, TY
